# How can i distinguish different protocols on Apache2 with reverse proxy?

Tags: apache, https, websocket, reverse-proxy

I need to set up a reverse proxy with Apache.
The remote website uses https and Web Socket Secure (wss).

I configured my Apache Web Server (version 2.2.22) in this way:

```
Listen 8443
<IfModule mod_websocket.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
SSLProxyEngine On

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Location />
        ProxyPass https://10.0.3.100/
        ProxyPassReverse https://10.0.3.100/
    </Location>
        <Location /dp/redirect>
        ProxyPass https://10.0.3.100/
        ProxyPassReverse https://10.0.3.100/
    </Location>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Location />
        ProxyPass https://10.0.3.100:8443/
        ProxyPassReverse https://10.0.3.100:8443/
    </Location>
        <Location /dp/redirect>
        ProxyPass https://10.0.3.100:8443/
        ProxyPassReverse https://10.0.3.100:8443/
    </Location>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn


        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I patched my Apache with mod_websocket (http://www.amoss.me.uk/2013/06/apache-2-2-websocket-proxying-ubuntu-mod_proxy_wstunnel/). The problem is that the Web Sockets don't work with that configuration.

I need a way to configure Apache to redirect wss request on port 8443 to wss://remote.server:8443, while https request on port 8443 to https://remote.server:8443 (so I need a way to "understand" the protocol request and redirect with the same protocol to the remote server).

How can I do? Thank you very much.